# uitableview cell creation on scrolling

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios4, uitableview

i am using uitableview and i am facing a problem in cellforrow delegate i use this code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"mycell";
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell =  (CustomCell *)[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:2];
    cell.btn_Selected.hidden=YES;
    cell.btn_Selected.tag=indexPath.row+1;

    [array_btnContainer addObject:cell.btn_Selected];

}
```

my problem is that when i run app it load my table view and create cells but when i scroll my table view it creates one more cell why ????
it must reuse the already created cell and not to enter (cell==nil) block but when ever i scroll it creates one cell and reuse other cell why???? i am stuck

Comment: How many rows are visible when the app starts up, and how many go off screen when you scroll?

Comment: Can you tell us the problem actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved via following these steps

1. Create a reference of your CustomCell in .h file which you are using to show the tableview whatever it is lets called it ShowTableView.h.
   IBOutlet  CustomCell *cell;
2. Go to CustomCell.xib and select the fileowner then set the class property as ShowTableView.
3. Attached the cell reference with the CustomCell
4. Select the CustomCell and then set property Identifier value with mycell
5. Now go to your ShowTableView.m file and cellForRowAtIndexPath method place this code:

   ```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:      (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {

   static NSString *kCellIdentifier = @"mycell";
   cell =(CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
   if (!cell)
   {
   [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];      
   }  
   }
   ```

Now it will reuse your previous cells

Answer (score 0):

In CustomCell.m you must overriding the following method as follows.

```
-(NSString*) reuseIdentifier{
       return @"mycell";
 }
```

Comment: is it possible that i stop creating more cell after scrolling and force to use old cell

Comment: how many cells are you creating? ie number of rows in a section

Comment: well u guys please tell me that is there any way so i can create cell in my own functions first and then just use that in cellforrow method